# How do I split a python source file into multiple files?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python 2.7.x source file say `test1.py` that contains:

```
 import a
 import b
 def def1():
      ...
 def def2():
      ...
 def def_confused():
      ...

 def def_crazy():
      ...
```

As I have been adding more and more features, It has become very complex. How can I automatically split it into `def1.py` , `def2.py` , `def_confused.py` , `def_crazy.py` etc ..

For example fsplit is a program that splits a large Fortran source file into  one file per subroutine. I am looking either an algorithm or a shell script or something similar that can achieve this task. Hopefully in python itself.

Comment: what do you mean by automatically?

Comment: added explanation

Comment: It is a bit hard to do automatic refactoring into multiple source files because some functions defined in a module B may depend on module A and you must place the correct imports in the top of the module - so I don't know any tool that will do this automatically. A good IDE like Pycharm help by highlighting missing definitions and automagically adding the correct import statement on ALT+ENTER.

Comment: In PyCharm you can use the Move refactoring...

Comment: BTW, while it is common to have one function definition per file in languages like C (helps to reduce build times) this is a bit too much for Python; in most flagship Python projects definitions are grouped in modules by affinity/domain. This may explain why a tool to split modules is not something popular: it is not common practice in Python.

Comment: useful to use an editor then. At the moment, I am okay if things get broken. It given me an opportunity to test everything again